# HTML Get element between ::before and ::after

Tags: html

I want to get the text "Example" from between these tags, but I don't know how to do it.

I thought of using a "getElementsByTagName("em")" method, but I only need this content, not all the em tags.

This is the example:

```
 <em> 
::before
Example
::after
</em>
```

Comment: You should use IDs on your elements and use getElementById(), or if you know which EM you are wanting in a sequence document.getElementsByTagName("em")[1].innerHTML should work?

Comment: `innerHTML` or `textContent`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are after is: `document.getElementsByTagName("em")[1].innerHTML`

This will get the text out of the `<em>` at position 2

by using the selector `[]` you tell it which element number you want by index.

```
<em>1</em>
<em>2</em>
<em>3</em>
<em>4</em>
```

using `document.getElementsByTagName("em")[1].innerHTML`
would return the number '2' (javascript indexes start at 0)

Alternatively, use ID's and use `getElementById()` instead, much easier when you know where the fish is in the barrel...